# how to use --patterns for tests in django

Tags: python, django, testing, automated-tests

I have a test file with tests in it which will not be called with the regular

`manage.py test`

command, only when I specifically tell django to do so.

So my file lives in the same folder as `tests.py` and its name is `test_blub.py`

I tried it with

`manage.py test --pattern="test_*.py"`

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the key is quite simple, the file is not supposed to start with test.

I named it `blub_test.py` and then called it with

`./manage.py test --pattern="blub_test.py"`

Comment: use double quotation marks is important here, doesn't work with `./manage.py test --pattern='blub_test.py'`